# jquery polyglot language switcher js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm suffering because I can not make a change in the language of a web page, I am using the plug in jquery.polyglot.language.switcher.js but I can not find documentation, I also followed the tutorial of the author and it does not work, ¿ Can you help me? I add the code

```
<div class="language-switcher float-right">
   <div id="polyglotLanguageSwitcher">
      <form action="#">
         <select id="polyglot-language-options">
            <option id="es" value="es" selected>Español</option>
            <option id="en" value="http://www.corporativovillamil.com/en/">English</option>
         </select>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS CODE

```
function languageSwitcher() {
    if ($("#polyglot-language-options").length) {
        $('#polyglotLanguageSwitcher').polyglotLanguageSwitcher({
            effect: 'slide',
            animSpeed: 500,
            testMode: true,
            onChange: function(evt) {
                alert("The selected language is: " + evt.selectedItem);
            }

        });
    };
}
```

everything works fine, the author mentions that code in custom.js so that's where I have to put something but I do not know where

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your problem. Do you have to switch from "http://www.corporativovillamil.com/es/" when you click on espanol to "http://www.corporativovillamil.com/en/" when you click on english (removing that alert)? Is this your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxofpower/kLdvf7am/8/) , it's how to use this js plugin , add this line of codes in your html page with script tag or javascript file:

```
    $(document).ready(function languageSwitcher() {
if ($("#polyglot-language-options").length) {
    $('#polyglotLanguageSwitcher').polyglotLanguageSwitcher({
        effect: 'slide',
        animSpeed: 500,
        testMode: true,
        onChange: function(evt) {
            alert("The selected language is: " + evt.selectedItem);
        }

    });
}
});
```

You also need to add this plugin reference to your html:

```
<script src="https://trampolim.com.br/assets/Polyglot-Language-Switcher-master/js/jquery.polyglot.language.switcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```